# Compiling retarget,c resulting in overlapping section

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

We are able to run assembly test cases (and basic C as well) on A53 cores in our environment.

As a next step, we wanted to bring-up the retarget.c changes, so as to enable printing from C.

Compile stage successfully went through and retarget.o got created. However, during linking we are running into the below error:-

/tools/armgcc/2020.11/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -Wl,-T verification/orion/sltb_uvm/CORE_SETUP/INFRA/link_csrc_aarch64.ld -lm -o main.elf objs/*.o

/tools/armgcc/2020.11/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: section DATA LMA [000000004000fa00,0000000040017fff] overlaps section .text.wcsnrtombs LMA [000000004000f9e0,000000004000fa17]

/tools/armgcc/2020.11/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: section .text._wctomb_r LMA [000000004000fa20,000000004000fa2f] *overlaps section DATA LMA [000000004000fa00,0000000040017fff]*

/tools/armgcc/2020.11/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: /tools/armgcc/2020.11/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/10.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r': /tmp/dgboter/bbs/build02--cen7x86_64/buildbot/cen7x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:83: undefined reference to` _getpid'

/tmp/dgboter/bbs/build02--cen7x86_64/buildbot/cen7x86_64--aarch64-none-elf/build/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:83:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_JUMP26 against undefined symbol `_getpid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1``

//--------------- End of error snippet-----------------

Please find the memory mapping in the .ld file

MEMORY

{
ddr_ram_code : ORIGIN = 0x40000000, LENGTH = 640K

ddr_ram_data : ORIGIN = 0x4000FA00, LENGTH = 1408K

}

Could you please help us with what could be missing from our side here? Am not sure why the memory overlap is being reported. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,
Arjun